# ARC `BAD_ACCESS` when using category method of NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, exc-bad-access

I call a utility method of mine like so:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd.MM.yy HH:mm"];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

return [[Environment sharedInstance].versionLabelFormat replaceTokensWithStrings:
     @"VERSION", APP_VERSION, 
     @"BUILD", APP_BULD_NUMBER, 
     @"DATETIME" , dateString, 
     nil ];
```

This is the `NSString` category method

```
-(NSString *)replaceTokensWithStrings:(NSString *)firstKey, ... NS_REQUIRES_NIL_TERMINATION{

    NSString *result = self;

        va_list _arguments;
        va_start(_arguments, firstKey);

        for (NSString *key = firstKey; key != nil; key = va_arg(_arguments, NSString*)) {

            // The value has to be copied to prevent crashes
            NSString *value = [(NSString *)(va_arg(_arguments, NSString*))copy];

            if(!value){
                // Every key has to have a value pair otherwise the replacement is invalid and nil is returned

                NSLog(@"Premature occurence of nil. Each token must be accompanied by a value: %@", result);
                return nil;
            }

            result = [result replaceToken:key withString:value];
        }
        va_end(_arguments);

    // Check if there are any tokens which were not yet replaced (for example if one value was nil)

    if([result rangeOfString:@"{"].location == NSNotFound){
        return result;
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Failed to replace tokens failed string still contains tokens: %@", result);
        return nil;
    }
}
```

No on the following line I had to add a `copy` statement otherwise there would be a Zombie with the `dateString`:

```
NSString *value = [(NSString *)(va_arg(_arguments, NSString*))copy];
```

To be more specific the *Zombie Report* told me this:

```
 1 Malloc       NSDateFormatter stringForObjectValue:
   Autorelease  NSDateFormatter stringForObjectValue:
 2 CFRetain     MyClass versionString:
 3 CFRetain     replaceToken:withString:
 2 CFRelease    replaceToken:withString:
 1 CFRelease    replaceTokensWithStrings:   ( One release too much!)
 0 CFRelease    MyClass versionString:
-1 Zombie       GSEventRunModal
```

Although the `copy` statement seems to fix the problem I would like to understand what is not ARC-complient with the code so that the `BAD_ACCESS` would occur without the `copy` for the value string.

Comment: okay it happened with me quite a few times. it seems like one the strings at a particular time get deallocated. USE NSZOMBIES to find the postion where your app crashes and then i created a strong property for the string which was getting de allocated. it Worked for me !!!!

Comment: @BrainStorms it is not a property but a readonly getter in my case. I did the Zombie checking so I found out where it happens, my question is more what part of my code is not ARC-compliant without the `copy` statement...

Comment: ARC doesn't know how to track Objective-C objects inside C arrays or C structs, so the problem probably comes from the variable arguments functions like va_arg().

Comment: @Besi under some circumstances (copy-ing an immutable object, for example), invoking copy may just increment the retain count and return the same object

Comment: @Guillaume That makes sense, so is the `copy`-method the right way to go then or should I use some `bridge`-type attribute? Curiously though is that the Crash does not always occur and as soon as I replace the `dateString` with @"someSting" then it does not crash anymore.

Comment: @Besi It makes sense, because string literals are compile time constants and are never deallocated, retained, or released.  I agree with Guillaume's reasoning.  This might have been an overlooked area when implementing the static analyzer.  If ARC is unable to handle it properly, then it should not allow the user to do it.

Comment: @Besi Out of curiosity, try putting the date string in the middle and see what happens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As others have stated the problem lies in the way you retrieve objects from the variable argument list which might not be compatible with ARC.

`va_arg` has a funny way of how to return a value of a specific type which ARC is probably not aware of. I'm not sure if this is a bug in clang or if it is the intended behavior for ARC. I'll clarify this issue and will update the post accordingly.

As a workaround just avoid the problem by using void pointers in the argument handling and convert them to objects properly in an ARC safe way:

```
for (NSString *key = firstKey; key != nil; key = (__bridge NSString *)va_arg(_arguments, void *)) {
    NSString *value = (__bridge NSString *)va_arg(_arguments, void *);
    NSAssert(value != NULL, @"Premature occurence of nil.");
    result = [result stringByReplacingToken:key
                                 withString:value];
}
```

**Edit:** The __bridge cast tells ARC to not do something about ownership. It just expects the object to be alive and does not transfer or give up ownership. Nevertheless the `key` and `value` variables maintain strong references to the objects while in use.

**Second Edit:** It seems that clang/ARC should be aware of the type in va_arg and either warn or just do the right thing ([see this, for example](http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project?view=rev&revision=136558)).

I tried to reproduce your problem without success. Everything works for me on:

```
$ clang --version
> Apple clang version 4.0 (tags/Apple/clang-421.10.48) (based on LLVM 3.1svn)
```

Which Xcode version do you use?

Comment: Does __bridge imply a strong retained object?

Comment: I have Xcode 4.3.3 and the command line tools installed, however, in Terminal it tells me I only have `Apple clang version 3.1 (tags/Apple/clang-318.0.61)` installed, hence clang 4.0 does not seem to be part of the latest Xcode?

Comment: That's right. My version is from Xcode 4.5 DP2. So maybe the bug is fixed since your version.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bug in clang.

### It should work

ARC **is compatible** with variable argument lists. If it wasn't you would get an error from the compiler.

The variable `value` is a strong reference whereas the result of `va_arg(_arguments, NSString *)` is an unsafe unretained reference: you may write `va_arg(_arguments, __unsafed_unretained NSString *)` and get the exact same compiled assembly but trying with another ownership-qualifier will get you a compiler error as it's not supported.

So, when storing the value in `value` and assuming the variable is actually used, the compiler should emit a call to `objc_retain` and balance it with a call to `objc_release` when the variable is destructed. According to the report, the second call is emitted whereas the first one is missing.

This lead to a crash with the string returned by `stringWithDate:` (and only this one) because it's the only string that isn't constant. All the other parameters are constant strings generated by the compiler, which simply ignore any memory management method, because they persist in memory as long as the executable is loaded.

So, we need to understand why the compiler emit a release without the corresponding retain. As you don't perform any manual memory management and don't trick the ownership rules by casting with `__bridge_transfer` or `__bridge_retained`, we can assume that the issue comes from the compiler.

### Undefined behavior isn't the reason

There are two reasons that may cause the compiler to emit invalid assembly. Either you code contains an undefined behavior either there is a bug in the compiler.

[Undefined behavior](http://blog.regehr.org/archives/213) occurs when your code try to perform something that is not defined by the C Standard: when the compiler meets an undefined behavior, it is entitled to do *whatever it wants*. Undefined behaviors result to programs that may or may not crash. Most of the time the issue occurs at the same place as the undefined behavior but sometimes it may seem unrelated because the compilers expect undefined behaviors not to occur and rely on that expectation to perform some optimizations.

So let's see if your code contains an undefined behavior. Yes it does, as the method `replaceTokensWithStrings:` may call `va_start` and return without `va_end` being called (`return nil` inside the `for` loop). The C Standard explicitly states (in section 7.15.1.3) that doing so is undefined behavior.

If we replace `return nil` with `break`, your code is now valid. However that doesn't solve the problem.

### Blame the compiler

Now that we eliminated all the other possible reasons, we need to face the reality. There is a bug in clang. We can see this by performing many subtle changes that produce valid compiled assembly:

- If we compile with `-O0` instead of `-Os`, it works.
- If we compile with clang 4.1, it works.
- If we send a message to the object before the `if` condition, it works.
- If we replace `va_arg(_arguments, NSString *)` with `va_arg(_arguments, id)`, it works. I suggest you use this workaround.

Comment: Nikolai's approach has proven to work too. Do you find `va_arg(_arguments, id)` is the better way to go and if yes, why?

Comment: I think `va_arg(_arguments, id)` is semantically closer to what you originally intended to write and simpler as it doesn't require an unnecessary cast. But both ways are valid and work the same after compiling. I wrote this answer first of all to explain *why* the problem occurred.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the insight, you didn't write clang, did you? :-)